# javascript - an assert function that doesnt require you to enter an error message

Tags: javascript, assert

Implementing an assert in javascript is not difficult:

```
assert = function(expression,errorMessage){
    if (!expression){
        errorMessage = errorMessage || "(no msg)";
        throw new Error("assert failed: "+errorMessage);
    }
    return true;
};
```

However, using this version of assert is tiresome because you have to have a meaningful error message for every test case:

```
var types = {isNumber:function(x){return typeof x === "number" && isFinite(x)}}

assert(types.isNumber(1)===true,"types.isNumber(1)===true");
assert(types.isNumber(NaN)===false,"types.isNumber(NaN)===false");
```

My question is that is there a way to implement the assert function such that it only takes one expression and it can return meaningful error message if that expression is not met? Like:

```
assert(SOMETHING_that_is_not_true); // throw Error: SOMETHINGELSE that refers to this particular assertion
assert(SOMETHING_that_is_not_true2); // throw Error: SOMETHINGELSE2 that refers to this different assertion
```

Comment: I think @James Thrope s solution will work, and I think that in your code you are not actually passing the expression, as it gets evaluated before it gets passed (aka if you run `assert(a == b)`, then javascript actually does `(a == b) = true` and actually runs `assert(true);`) I'm not 100% sure, but I think expression that are passed are evaluated before actually being passed.

Comment: Yes that is basically why you need to pass in error message. I like @James Thropes's solution too but I will wait to see if there are better ideas

Comment: Then James Thropes solution _is the only solution_ as its the only way to actually pass the expression without repeating it inside a string, and without pre-evaluating it. Unless you use....... `eval` ......... DANGER DANGER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more code than a simple expression for each assertion, but how about this?

```
assert = function(expression){
    if (!expression()){
        errorMessage = expression.toString() || "(no msg)";
        throw new Error("assert failed: "+errorMessage);
    }
    return true;
};

assert(function() { return 'b' == 'a' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add this as it **will** work. But it is

### Not advised

As it uses eval, which is, juck. But it is useful if you don't face it to the client. (What am I saying? It is not advised. End of that. But it does work.)

```
function assert(expression){
    var success = eval(expression);
    if(!success) throw new Error("assert failed: "+ expression);
    else return true;
}
```

Then you can do

```
assert("types.isNumber(1)===true");
```

So te reiterate, use @James Thorpe s code (hopefully) above.

Comment: I tried this method but there were some issues with eval context like not finding the variables/functions.